# Expectation of product of three jointly Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

given $X_1,X_2,X_3∼N(0,σ^2)$ , jointly gaussian with $E[X_iX_j] \ne 0$

Why does $E[X_1X_2X_3]=0 $?

Also, given $X= [X_1,X_2,...X_k]$ ,  $X_i∼N(0,σ^2)$ jointly gaussian:

Is it true that $E$[ product of n=odd different variables ]$=0$?

Comment: The result can refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem You may view like this: By Cholesky Decomposition on the covariance matrix, all elements in multivariate normal vector $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_k$ can be expressed as a linear combinations of independent normal $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots Z_k$ (same dimension). If the dimension is odd, then there exist at least one of $Z_i$ with odd power. And thus by independence and the odd moments is zero, the whole expectation is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that there should be a simpler proof, but if we can use [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant), we have that
\begin{multline*}
\operatorname E[X_1X_2X_3]
=\operatorname{cum}[X_1,X_2,X_3]+\operatorname{cum}[X_1]\operatorname{cum}[X_2,X_3]+\operatorname{cum}[X_2]\operatorname{cum}[X_1,X_3]\\
+\operatorname{cum}[X_3]\operatorname{cum}[X_1,X_2]
+\operatorname{cum}[X_1]\operatorname{cum}[X_2]\operatorname{cum}[X_3].
\end{multline*}
You can find this equality on page 34 of Stationary sequences and random fields by Murray Rosenblatt. Now since all joint cumulants of order greater than $2$ of a Gaussian distribution are $0$, $\operatorname{cum}[X_1,X_2,X_3]=0$. Also, $\operatorname{cum}[X_i]=\operatorname EX_i=0$ for $i=1,2,3$. Hence, $\operatorname E[X_1X_2X_3]=0$.

Using similar arguments, we can show that a product of odd number of random variables with joint Gaussian distribution is also equal to $0$.